# Why does reading my depth texture in GLSL return less than one?

Tags: opengl, glsl, depth-buffer, frame-buffer, depth

I've created a depth texture in OpenGL (using C#) as follows:

```
// Create the framebuffer.
var framebuffer = 0u;

glGenFramebuffers(1, &framebuffer);
glBindFramebuffer(GL_FRAMEBUFFER, framebuffer);

// Create the depth texture.
var depthTexture = 0u;

glGenTextures(1, &depthTexture);
glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, depthTexture);
glTexImage2D(GL_TEXTURE_2D, 0, GL_DEPTH_COMPONENT24, 800, 600, 0, GL_DEPTH_COMPONENT, GL_FLOAT, null);
glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_WRAP_S, GL_REPEAT);
glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_WRAP_T, GL_REPEAT);
glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_MIN_FILTER, GL_NEAREST);
glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_MAG_FILTER, GL_NEAREST);
glFramebufferTexture2D(GL_FRAMEBUFFER, GL_DEPTH_ATTACHMENT, GL_TEXTURE_2D, depthTexture, 0);
```

Later, I sample from the depth texture as follows:

```
float depth = texture(depthTexture, texCoords).r;
```

But even when no geometry has been rendered to that pixel, the depth value coming back is less than 1 (seems to be very slightly above 0.5). This is confusing to me since, per the documentation on `glClearDepth`, the default value is 1. Note that this is *not* a problem of linearizing depth since I'm attemping to compare depth directly (using the same near and far planes), not convert that depth back to world space.

**Why is my depth texture sample returning <1 when no geometry has been rendered?**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved it! The problem resulted from sharing a depth texture between two framebuffers. The reason for sharing the texture is that my question was actually simplified compared to reality: it's actually a depth-*stencil* buffer, since I need to share the stencil buffer between two framebuffers while the second reads depth values from the first.

The first framebuffer is generated as shown in my question (except that I used `GL_DEPTH_STENCIL_ATTACHMENT` rather than just `GL_DEPTH_ATTACHMENT`). The second looks like this:

```
var secondBuffer = 0u;

glGenFramebuffers(1, &secondBuffer);
glBindFramebuffer(GL_FRAMEBUFFER, secondBuffer);
glFramebufferTexture2D(GL_FRAMEBUFFER, GL_DEPTH_STENCIL_ATTACHMENT, GL_TEXTURE_2D, depthStencilTexture, 0);
```

Later (after rendering the first framebuffer), I render to the second as follows:

```
glActiveTexture(GL_TEXTURE0);
glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, depthStencilTexture);

quad.Draw();
```

The fix was to **toggle depth testing before and after the draw call**:

```
glActiveTexture(GL_TEXTURE0);
glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, depthStencilTexture);
glDisable(GL_DEPTH_TEST);

quad.Draw();

glEnable(GL_DEPTH_TEST);
```

As for *why* toggling depth testing fixes the problem (or conversely, why *not* toggling caused the depth value in GLSL to be slightly > 0.5), I'm not sure. Hoping this answer helps someone else in the future!